# Return from Service to Controller time in Grails

Tags: performance, spring, grails, spring-mvc

We are working on performance in our grails app, and it seems like grails needs much time (7-13ms) to get out of Service back to Controller. The data that is returned is reference to domain objects (Map with 2 references), not very complex. Is there any way to shorten this time?

We have log.debug() before return statement in service, and another one after leaving service, in controller.

```
2012-02-01 15:16:07,048 [http-8080-1] DEBUG api.TestService test before service return
2012-02-01 15:16:07,063 [http-8080-1] DEBUG api.TestController test after service return
```

Edit: Grails version 1.3.7

Edit: After turning on hibernate SQL logging:

```
2012-02-02 09:20:04,504 [http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] DEBUG api.TestService before return
2012-02-02 09:20:04,505 [http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] DEBUG hibernate.SQL select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2012-02-02 09:20:04,516 [http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] DEBUG hibernate.SQL insert into test ...
2012-02-02 09:20:04,520 [http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] DEBUG hibernate.SQL update test1 ...
2012-02-02 09:20:04,522 [http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] DEBUG hibernate.SQL insert into test_test1 ...
2012-02-02 09:20:04,524 [http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-1] DEBUG api.TestController after service
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger, going down inside the grails guts, to see where it's going?

Comment: Can you provide some for info what are you doing in the service? How many elements has the map? Code snippets?

Comment: Seriously? You're concerned about 7 to 13 _milliseconds_ ?

Comment: doh! 7 to 13 milliseconds in an api which takes 60ms is 1/5 of time! 100 requests with 10ms wasted equal to a wasted second :)

Comment: something on the topic: would the contents of map matter? It should be reference passed and not the object itself.

Comment: I`ve made new simple project, with one simple domain class, service and controller, and it seems like there is no time leak when leaving service. It looks like we have some issues with those 2 returned objects. In other hand, i was pretty sure returning reference does not last so long.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the logging statement themselves will add some tiny amount of delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overhead might be caused by Spring building a transaction context around the service call (Grails default, see http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/services.html#declarativeTransactions).
If your service doesn't require (database) transactions, make sure you add

```
static transactional = false
```

in the service.

If you do need transactions and you are doing a lot of service calls from a controller, it's worth moving them to a service so that you have the minimum amount of transactions to deal with. (If you absolutely want to keep them in the controller, withTransaction block can be used to do several service calls in a single transaction.)

Comment: You`re right. After adding some more logging we`ve noticed, the transaction ends when leaving Service, and the inserts and updates last so long. I`ve edited the question with logs after turning on hibernate SQL debug.

Answer (score 2):

7 to 13 milliseconds is pretty much instantaneous. You're wasting your time trying to reduce this further. Surely you must have other more important things to do?

Even if this is your most pressing concern, there seems little point in spending time on it,  because there's really nothing you can do about it, because it's Grails/Spring code (rather than yours) than executes between the service and controller.

Comment: So you're saying that 7 to 13 milliseconds to return from one method to another is ok? It's not the API call that takes 7-13ms but just going from service to controller. So in order to meet the SLAs this is one of the things to look into.

Comment: Yep. If you're concerned about millisecond performance, you should be coding your application in finely tuned assembly language.

Comment: Burt, I don't agree.I think you are going from one extreme [don't care about performance] to another [performance is the king].What we want to do is to write in something flexible as Grails and squeeze from it as much as we can.When doing so we are looking for bottlenecks which are easy to fine tune [like for example moving long loops to java]. We have found that in simple return from service to controller we are loosing more than 1/4 time of some apis.Since we couldn't find why, we decided to ask. Do tell, how is this wrong?It would be if it was a webapp for 10 users, but that's not the case.